# 3DS Max Making 45Deg Miters

Tags: 3ds-max, modeling

I'm making a molding for a wall. I have a completely vertical piece and a completely horizontal piece. At the top cap of the vertical piece I want to make a 45 deg miter to join with the horizontal piece.

I tried selecting all the vertices then doing 'Edge Constrain' with 'Selection Center', but it bugs out and rotates only half of the vertices. It rotates properly with 'None Constrain' but then it scales itself down in the horizontal direction. I also tried other 'Selection Modes' with different constraints and none work.

Comment: Why not use a boolean function to get a perfect joint?

Comment: Edge-constraining will bug out when corner vertices are involved. Can you post a picture of your starting model components? I'm not entirely sure where you're running into the issue